# Permanently save ajax data in PHP variable

Tags: php, ajax

I can send data from Ajax to PHP and receive response in Ajax. Is there any way to save the Ajax data in PHP and use it inside PHP page ?

Comment: try to store data into session. Once you are done with it, destroy session value

Comment: What are you trying to achieve as there maybe other ways of doing getting the results that you require.

Comment: I want to use a php function `file_get_contents(url)`, Where URL is being stored from ajax on PHP page as PHP variable.

Comment: @ShivaniPatel Are you sure Session can do this ? I tried but did not get the result

Comment: You can put your `url` which you are getting from response in some `hidden field` and then used that field  to set in session.

Comment: @Swati please write an example if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    url:"<?= site_url('index/get_data') ?>",
    type:'post',
    dataType:'json',
    success: function (data) {
        $('div').html(data);
    }
});
```

you can set dynamic data using jquery but I think it is not possible to save ajax response as a php variable

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `function`and call  it on ajax `success` function , lastly there are two way to put value to `php` either by `form submit` or `ajax`.I have use ajax method i.e :

```
 function result(r){
//"r" have response value 
 //pass to ajax
 alert("i'm in");
   $.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "page1.php",  
    data: { 'value': r},      
    success: function(response){
      alert("done");
    },
   error: function (jqXHR) {
   console.log(jqXHR);
   alert("There was a problem");
  }
}); 

 }

$.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "page.php",  
        success: function(response){
         //passing response value to function "result"  
          result(response);
        },
       error: function (jqXHR) {
       console.log(jqXHR);
       alert("There was a problem");
      }
 });
```

Now in `page1.php` write like below :

```
<?php
session_start();
//putting value in session
$_SESSION['url'] = $_POST['value'];   
?>
```

Comment: I think second ajax request is not working.

Comment: In second jquery call write like this `alert(value);` and see does it give any alert or not .

Comment: no it's not alerting anything

Comment: Is there any error in your `console` ?

Comment: No, there is no error in console even. But I think we should do something to call the Jquery after loading the first Ajax.

Comment: Even can not alert after this line :  `$('#myhiddenField').on('input', function() {`

Comment: i have edited above code , made it more easier , try and check if it works or  not .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195758/discussion-between-swapnil-rajja-and-swati).